# Table rows toggle() with jQuery and DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a small table with some rows and some of them with extra information which will be show or hide with jQuery toggle(). Everything works fine but I can't use DataTable in this context. My jQuery looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#serien tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

            if ( $(this).hasClass('showDetails') ) {
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('shown');
            }

            $(this).toggleClass('showDetails');
            $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        });
    });
```

But when I want to use DataTable - in the easiest way like https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#serien').DataTable();

        $('#serien tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var data = table.row( this ).data();
            alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
        } );
    } );
```

It won't work, can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Also, could you please post related `HTML` too? and if possible add a sample fiddle or snippet..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` to pass into the `row()` function. `this` in this context points to the td. You should be passing in that td's parent tr element instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#serien').DataTable();

    $('#serien tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).closest("tr")[0] ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I tried it but I will receive the same error [code]TypeError: i is undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:24:271

Answer (score 0):

A part of the table looks like

```
<table id="serien" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
      <th colspan="3">The Avengers</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Vorname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
    <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td>Peel</td>
      <td>Emma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showDetails">
      <td colspan="3">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Vorname</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>  
            <td>Rigg</td><td>Diana</td>           
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      ....
    </tbody>        
</table>
```